No explicit visual indication WHILE an app is running with elevated privileges?
A security vulnerability still exists in the current version of Windows 11 Pro:
A malware program could somehow run an elevated application without the user noticing the program is running with elevated rights.
While Windows provides some level of security indication BEFORE an application runs with elevated privileges (the UAC prompt), there is no explicit visual indication, such as a shield overlay icon on the application's taskbar button, WHILE the application is running with elevated privileges.
Is there a way to protect from this vulnerability?

A program cannot receive elevated permissions without an UAC prompt. What you describe isn’t actually a vulnerability. This is the reason the recommendation is to run everything as a user with Administrator permissions. If you choose not to do that then you disregard best practices

A malware program can secretly modify the UAC modality. See here: https://app.screencast.com/JUl4Wn9c5HJ3K

Still doesn’t make it a vulnerability. That’s like saying malicious Linux malware can run sudo, that screenshot does NOT disable UAC.

That's not a vulnerability, just a personal preference.

A malware program could somehow run an elevated application without the user noticing the program is running with elevated rights.

Then that malware could have already manipulated the system, suppressing the 'visual indication' or run hidden entirely.
You might be forgetting that a human's reaction is too slow by several magnitudes to stop a computer from doing bad things. In a blink of the eye - literally - a computer runs several billion operations.
The point is there can't be a 'somehow run an elevated application' unless the user has explicitly authorized it.
And after all, what good would it do to get an indication AFTER all the damage has been done?

"The point is there can't be a 'somehow run an elevated application' unless the user has explicitly authorized it."
Then, you don't know the practices of smart hackers.

As @user1580348 states, Task Manager, Startup folder and other means exist and are used for running an app as Admin or System. That said, whether that is a vulnerability, or not, is a matter of opinion. Not only Windows, but other OS's behave the same, so the developers must consider it acceptable. Use Task Manager or Gnome System Monitor or other utility to see what credentials are used by processes, including those hidden.
